# I want to call a function after checkout in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making an ecommerce website using woocommerce, now I want to call a function after use fill the checkout form and submit it. Is there any filter or hooks that allow me to do that?

Comment: There are plenty of hooks. Why don't you look in the source code? For example, [`woocommerce_payment_complete`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L2332) comes to mind, but your question is so vague no one can give you a really good recommendation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you can:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array('Wc_class', 'my_uber_function'));
class Wc_class{
 public static function my_uber_function($order_id)
 {
    stuff to do here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something after WooCommerce order completed you can hook into woocommerce_order_status_completed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_function' );
/*
 * Do something after WooCommerce sets an order on completed
 */
function my_function($order_id) {

    // order object (optional but handy)
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    // do some stuff here

}
```